# Entity misbehaving whilst rendering PDF with twig, symfony2 and doctrine

Tags: symfony, pdf, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm facing a funny issue here, I will do my best to explain it:

I have an **Order** entity and an **orderProducts** with a one to many relation.

Now I'm trying to generate a PDF invoice.

So I built my invoice using twig, then I [use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) then it's just the following

```
$snappy = new Pdf($myProjectDirectory . 'vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386');
$renderedView = $this->renderView(
    'ERPBundle:Orders:invoicepdf.html.twig', array(
        'order' => $order,
        'invoice' => $invoice
    )
);
$snappy->generateFromHtml($renderedView, $invoicePath);
```

In the generated PDF, the orderProducts are duplicated, meaning I get the same row displayed twice.

I've rendered the template separately to view it in the browser and the orderProdcuts displays correctly, I used the same code to retrieve the data.

So I'm guessing this has got to be an issue between Snappy rendering of the html output + doctrine's lazy load. But I don't have the skills to debug this.

Comment: Have you tried this using the KnpSnappyBundle instead and calling it as a service?  Are you sure there aren't any hidden values displaying multiple times?

Comment: I'll try the KnpSnappyBundle, and yes I'm sure about the values. It is a little freaky, I dump the length of the array collection in rendering and it's always doubled when I'm generating the pdf

Comment: Let me know what happens, maybe you have a hidden `dump` somewhere?

Comment: Tried it same output. feel free to check it out [controller](https://github.com/alexseif/miniERP/blob/master/src/MeVisa/ERPBundle/Controller/OrdersController.php#L559) & [view](https://github.com/alexseif/miniERP/blob/master/src/MeVisa/ERPBundle/Resources/views/Orders/invoicepdf.html.twig#L105)

Comment: comment out the loop altogether and see if it's still displaying i suppose

Comment: wait, what? that doesn't make sense to me. If I comment out the loop, then how will I display the order products? and if you mean I shouldn't display them, then I don't have a problem. Here's also what i have tried, I have tried to query the order products separately, still same issue. Now I will try to make an array and see what happens

Comment: i just meant for debugging, comment it out and see if they're still displaying somehow.  basically just go through piece by piece and see if you can find the errant behavior.

Comment: Thanx Jason a lot, actually it's my bad, issue completely irrelevant from this code. I generate an invoice after a certain update, and I mistakenly addOrderProduct. Now doctrine realizes that this is the same order product and so it doesn't duplicate the content in the db. [line that produces the error](https://github.com/alexseif/miniERP/blob/master/src/MeVisa/ERPBundle/Controller/OrdersController.php#L559) Now I just check `empty(orderProduct->getId())` before I addOrderProduct. Now I need help to close this question, if you would be so kind :)

Comment: You can answer your own question with the code that caused the error and the code that fixed it and mark it as resolved

Comment: Thanx again @jasonRoman but you know what's bothering me, is that fetching the entity from the db was totally ignored, it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is irrelevant to this code or the relative bundles.
The invoice PDF was generated after a form update, and in assigning my sub entity values I did this:

```
$orderProducts = $order->getOrderProducts();
foreach ($orderProducts as $orderProduct) {
         $order->addOrderProduct($orderProduct);
}
```

This generated the duplicate value for orderProducts, I didn't catch this before, because doctrine recognizes the duplication and ignores it.
The fix is to properly handle the update like this

```
$orderProducts = $order->getOrderProducts();
foreach ($orderProducts as $orderProduct) {
    $order->addOrderProduct($orderProduct);
    if (empty($orderProduct->getId())) {
        $order->addOrderProduct($orderProduct);
    }
}
```

[link to fix](https://github.com/alexseif/miniERP/commit/d50e9f45fb502e0f39fe45d4564edff6ba0a3a76#diff-b84e858d7b041cafb8bf38cded3280d6)